# How to install epel-release in Red Hat linux 7.8

Tags: rhel

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo) and when I try to run.

```
yum install epel-release
```

> No package epel-release available.

> Error: Nothing to do

I need to install this for DKMS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

You have to do this because `epel-release` package is directly available in CentOS base repository, but not in RHEL repository.

According to [documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), it is also recommended to enable some optional repositories:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable "rhel-*-optional-rpms" --enable "rhel-*-extras-rpms"  --enable "rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms"
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the command below as http: (not https:):

```
yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

to avoid the error:

```
Cannot open: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
```

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment on [Danila Vershinin's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598051/80216).

Comment: That is true, I'll edit my post by turning it into a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' With such low reputation comment is not allowed for him, I think.